# How to create a Xamarin.Forms custom renderer, where the renderer base class uses generics?

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a base class, which looks like the following

```
public class DialogSelectionItem<Tobject> : ViewCell
```

Now I want to attach a custom renderer to it:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SomeApp.CustomRenderers.DialogSelectionItem<Tobject>), typeof(SomeApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.DialogSelectionItemRenderer))]
namespace SomeApp.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class DialogSelectionItemRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        // some customizations
    }
}
```

The problem is

> The type or namespace name 'Tobject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can use `object` instead, but then the custom renderer is never called.

Is there an option to get the correct type or use the generic? How should I define the `ExportRenderer`?

Comment: How are you using your custom ViewCell in XAML?

Comment: I just tested that but with a generic Label and used `typeof(CustomLabel<object>)` and it was called successfully.

Comment: @Vahid: I'm calling it like so `ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DialogSelectionItem<Tobject>))`. In my case the app seems to be depending on the type. And `object` is none of my *valid* types. At least as I see as explanation for the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the solution is posted [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/132734/#Comment_132734).

**Base class:**

```
public class DialogSelectionItem : ViewCell
{
    // nothing
}

public class DialogSelectionItem<Tobject> : DialogSelectionItem
{
    // do something
}
```

**View renderer:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SomeApp.CustomRenderers.DialogSelectionItem), typeof(SomeApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.DialogSelectionItemRenderer))]
namespace SomeApp.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class DialogSelectionItemRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        // some customizations
    }
}
```